# Place sequencing information in each message SQs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

As most of know AWS-SQS provides highly scalable and reliable queue servicing for messages but it does not provide the FIFO behaviour of a queue as to make it highly reliable it keeps data on multiple places.

In their F&Q they said we can place sequencing information in each message.

Can any one help with a brief idea, what do they exactly mean by this?

How do we keep the records in order by this? Let's say I am pushing 10k to 20k records and pulling out 1K or 2K records then how it will ensure the order? Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure the ordering in your code by putting the sequence number in the body of your message and then checking that in your consumer.

You can skip the messages that are out of order by not acknowledging them, causing them to be redelivered after the visibility timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply greg .

As i mentioned in my question, the problem here is we are getting a high volume of data in the queue on input approx 10k and i am fetching 1K.

I have some 10 records to save in order , but what if all 10 records doesn't come in same request? Do i save the records in my code for the meanwhile?